# Why is the test failing when comparing two of the same objects in Java?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying to make a polynomial calculator to learn how to code and as I'm testing it there's a part which fails when comparing two of the same objects which is not making any sense to me. See the following test unit that is failing.

```java
@Test
public void testAddition() {
        P1 = new PolynomialImp("12x^2+5");
        P2 = new PolynomialImp("16x^2+6");
        Polynomial P3 = P1.add(P2);
        Polynomial P4 = new PolynomialImp("28x^3+11");
        assertTrue(P3.equals(P4));
        
    }
```

The thing is, it fails even when I change the tester to the following.

```java
@Test
public void testAddition() {
        P1 = new PolynomialImp("12x^3+5");
        P2 = new PolynomialImp("16x^3+6");
        Polynomial P3 = new PolynomialImp("28x^3+11");
        Polynomial P4 = new PolynomialImp("28x^3+11");
        assertTrue(P3.equals(P4));
    }
```

Shouldn't it pass considering they are both created with the same variables?

Comment: You should show your `PolynomialImp` class.

Comment: The first test _is_ to fail because `12x^2 + 16x^2` make `28x^2` - not `28x^3`.  As for the second test sample it's impossible to tell what's wrong without any information about implementation of `PolynomialImp` class and especially its `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default implementation of `equals()` is only true when both objects are the same object, so only for P3.equals(P3) or if you do

```
P3 = new ...
P4 = P3;
P3.equals(P4); // true
```

If you need equivality based on the logic of your program (i.e. 2 polynomials are equal if they are initialized with the same string), you have to override the equals() methof of your class and implement that logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`P3.equals(P4)` checks whether P3 and P4 are the same instance of an object. You have to override the `equals` method to return `true` or `false` accordingly.

Comment: I see. So every time I want to compare two custom objects that I create I would need to override the equals method to specify how the new objects should be compared right?